# Redirect to different ports based on request URL

Tags: windows, tomcat, iis, redirect, dns

I'm using **Windows Server 2003**. I have one web application running on **IIS** and another web application running on **Apache Tomcat**. Currently all requests go to port `80`. From what I understand, Tomcat and IIS cannot use the same port simultaneously. Therefore I need a way to redirect users. If a user goes to **www.example.com** then I need them to use `http://localhost:80` but if they go to **www.otherExample.com** then I need them to use `http://localhost:8084/otherExample`

How does this generally get done?

Comment: Is this a test/dev or production environment?

Comment: Why do you have to use two different types of servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set IIS to port 80.
2. Create two virtual hosts on IIS for your two domains.
3. Set the document root of the first to a directory on your IIS.
4. Remove the coyote http/1 connector from Tomcat.
5. Look [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html), how to redirect from your IIS to Tomcat.
6. Map the second virtual host to Tomcat according to the tutorial.

Then you can access example.com and otherExample.com without ports or directory changes.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you should go with something like this:

First of all, I will assume that you know how to map **example.com** and **otherexample.com** to **127.0.0.1** and that is really what you want. So I will skip that part and go straight to configuration.

First of all, when users type **http://www.domain.com** it is **EXACTLY THE SAME** as typing **http://www.domain.com:80**. Also, when users type **https://www.domain.com** it is **EXACTLY THE SAME** as typing **https://www.domain.com:443**. That means, if you omit the ports for https and https, 80 and 443 are assumed respectively.

So, this brings you to only one conclusion. You have to set one web server (IIS or Tomcat) to port 80, and another to port 8084. You decide which is which, because for configuration it is irrelevant.

Now, to accomplish what you need, you need to create a redirection script **on the server which listens to port 80**. So, if you use PHP for redirection script, you could use something like this:

```
<?php

  if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=='www.otherexample.com') {
    Header('Location: http://localhost:8084/otherExample');
  }

?>
```

Also, you could accomplish something similar using configuration file of the server itself (the one that is listening on port 80).

This is only general explanation of the steps you need to take. Obviously, you will need to adapt them to work for your case.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: If your IIS is set up to run on port 80, and you can run php on your IIS, then put my code as index.php in your root, and see what happens (assuming that domains are example.com or otherexample.com).

Comment: Are your domains really www.example.com and www.otherexample.com ?

Comment: Well, for windows you can add `127.0.0.1 example.com` and `127.0.0.1 otherexample.com` in your `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file and then run `ipconfig /flushdns` in your console. For linux, same can be added to `/etc/hosts`. Then, when you ping example.com or ping otherexample.com, you should get a reply from 127.0.0.1 which is basically localhost.